# Как сделать игру "Города" для бота теллеграм на Python?

Tags: python, telebot

Здравсвуйте, я Junior Python-программист. Я умею делать Телеграмм-ботов на Python с помощью пакета pyTelegramBotAPI. И я хочу добавить к своему боту игру "Города" (Города́ — игра, в которой каждый участник в свою очередь называет реально существующий город любой страны, название которого начинается на ту букву, которой оканчивается название предыдущего города). Я не могу сделать цикл игры так, чтобы бот видил последнюю букву города и называл на эту букву тот или иной город. Надеюсь вы мне поможете с моим вопросом.

Comment: в чём сложность найти последнюю букву  ? покажите ваши неправильные попытки. города для ответа откуда планируете брать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе стоит найти сервис, который предоставляет базу всех городов мира, и потом уже if-ами будешь писать игру

и маленький советик лично от меня: используй aiogram, а не pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Большое  спасибо!

Comment: Советы стоит чем-то подкреплять, потому что в текущем варианте это выглядит равносильно надписи на заборе.

Comment: она асинхронна

Представим есть 100 юзеров, которые нажали кнопку /старт
если бот не асинхронный, то 100-му юзеру нужно будет ждать, пока бот ответит остальным 99м пользователям. асинхронность же решает данную проблему